# ASP.NET Core Expose Config to DI Injected Service

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core WebAPI project and I am trying to add configuration to my `IEmailService`that I am injecting through DI like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
```

How can instances of `AuthMessageSender` get to settings in the config file?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should use the [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#use-options-and-configuration-objects) pattern with strongly typed configuration:

1. Create your `EmailSettings` strongly typed configuration class:

```cs
public class EmailSettings  
{
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

2. Update your *appsettings.json* to include a configuration section that maps to your `EmailSettings` configuration class:

```js
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "EmailSettings": {
    "HostName": "myhost.com",
    "Username": "me",
    "Password": "mysupersecretpassword",
  }
}
```

3. In the `ConfigureServices` call of your `Startup` class, bind *appsettings.json* to your config class

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{
    services.Configure<MySettings>(
          options => Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings").Bind(options));
}
```

4. In your `AuthMessageSender` class, inject an instance of `IOptions<EmailSettings>` into the constructor

```cs
public class AuthMessageSender
{
    private readonly EmailSettings _settings;
    public AuthMessageSender(IOptions<EmailSettings> emailSettings)
    {
       _settings = emailSettings.Value;
      // _settings.HostName == "myhost.com";
    }
}
```

---

Note that in step 3, you can also use

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{
    services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
}
```

If you add a reference to *Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions* in *project.json*:

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
     "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended pattern is to read the specific config entries you need [at startup](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/samples/MusicStore/Startup.cs#L36) and store them in an Options instance in DI, and inject that specific options type [into your other components](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/6435591d1cc0a9b27182337b5ae572770973b784/src/MusicStore/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L17).

Comment: First link is dead.  Please post ALL relevant code instead of just linking to external resources.