# Why is static Configuration.GetSection() not available?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core 3.1 project I am trying to read a configuration option from "appsettings.json" via dependency injection service container just as explained [by the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration&view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-options-and-configuration-objects) or also by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38110452/2484903).

But whenever I come to the point where I need to add `Configuration.GetSection` to `ConfigureServices()` in "Startup.cs", I am getting error:

```
CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Configuration.GetSection(string)'
```

[image]

[`static Configuration.GetSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configuration.getsection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) is part of ".NET Platform extensions 3.1". Do I need to install a dependency/add an assembly?

I already tried installing [NuGet ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/).

Comment: The method you link to isn't static, it's `public ConfigurationSection GetSection (string sectionName)`. No documentation example treats this as static

Comment: Right, I just noticed, too. But where is the static version defined then?

Comment: There isn't one. There can't be one - there's no global configuration, configuration is loaded at runtime explicitly, either by application code or the Host class, based on the application's configuration code. `Startup` methods receive an `IConfiguration` instance they use to retrieve config values. That's typically saved in a `Configuration` field to make `Startup` cleaner

Comment: Other classes should receive that instance from their caller. With controllers, it's injected by the DI container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those examples from MS site do not call `GetSection` as static method:

```
public class Test21Model : PageModel
{
    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
    public PositionOptions positionOptions { get; private set; }

    public Test21Model(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public ContentResult OnGet()
    {            
        positionOptions = Configuration.GetSection(PositionOptions.Position)
                                                     .Get<PositionOptions>();

        return Content($"Title: {positionOptions.Title} \n" +
                       $"Name: {positionOptions.Name}");
    }
}
```

So you need to define class property `Configuration` and instantiate it in the constructor, as in the example - and then call that method on instance of the class.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really missed line "Configuration = configuration" because I was not interested in a model but in startup. But this answer lead me into the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

in Program.cs

change:

> builder.Services.Configure(Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings"));

to:

> builder.Services.Configure(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings"));

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Panagiotis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) and [kosist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6917446/kosist),
I found out that the question boils down to "**How to access `Configuration` in startup?**"

The answer is in the comments ("injected by the DI") and as code [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration&view=aspnetcore-3.1#access-configuration-in-startup):

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<PositionOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(PositionOptions.Position));
    }
}
```